# C# Hashtable vs c++ hash_map

Tags: c#, c++

I'm comparing the following code in C++ and C# and C# (Mono 2.4) seems to be faster. Is there anything wrong with the C++ code?

```
 #include <map>
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ext/hash_map>
 #include <boost/any.hpp>

 int main()
 {
    //std::map<long, long> m;
    // hash_map is a little bit faster
    __gnu_cxx::hash_map<long, long> m;

    for( long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    {
        m[i]  = i;
    }

 }
```

And C#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;

 public int Main()
 {
     Hashtable m = new Hashtable();

     for( long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
     {
        m[i]  = i;
     }

}
```

C# code is actually twice as fast on the same machine.

```
$ time ./a.out

real    0m1.028s
user    0m0.986s
sys     0m0.041s

$ time mono test.exe

real    0m0.603s
user    0m0.732s
sys     0m0.090s
```

Comment: Did you compile the C++ code with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Also note that initial hash map sizes may be different.  E.g., if the C# is larger, and C++ version lower, you might easily see a big differences.

Comment: Have you tried Boost.Unordered?

Comment: What OS are you on? Is the C++ binary stripped? Is it statically or dynamically linking the a.out file.

Comment: Hi. I just compiled with gcc test.cc. No switches, nothing. 

Didn't try with the default sizes either, but the Mono/C# default size is not very big either.

Didn't try Boost.Unordered. The old fedora I'm using doesn't seem to have it. I'll look at a newer box (ok, or I'll install it :-P).

Comment: $ uname -a

Linux juno 2.6.11-1.1369_FC4smp #1 SMP Thu Jun 2 23:08:39 EDT 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep bogo

bogomips        : 5931.00
bogomips        : 5980.16

Comment: Remember also that with the mono version that you are timing the startup of the runtime, compilation of the code, and then executing the code. Just something to keep in mind. To time just the code execution itself take a look at the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class.

Comment: That's true joshperry. In fact, I should measure just the code INSIDE the main method instead of everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compile the C++ code with compiler optimizations turned on for a fair comparison. Otherwise, you are comparing apples to debug builds — the compiler will not even *try* to emit fast code.

In GCC this would be the `-O3` flag, to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Some thoughts:

- You're comparing Mono against Boost
- Which optimization (default or not) settings did you use for Mono and C++ ?
- What are the initial / default hash table sizes for the C# and C++ versions ?
- Have you tried comparing against other C++ hash maps, such as [the sparse hash table](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) ?
- Remember not only to look at *real* time, but actual CPU time used.

Comment: I'd like to know how much faster Boost is. Didn't enable any optimizations for Mono nor C++. Not sure about the table sizes, I'll have to check. Considering other hashtables is exactly what I'd like to do. Yep, but even real+user is better for Mono.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Boost is that much faster.  I don't think there have been great improvements in hash_map implementations the last few years.  (Btw, your Linux setup might have the std::tr1::unordered_map, which is another hashing container implementation...)